# php5-fpm does not kill its children ondemand

Tags: php, nginx

I have this simple /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:

```
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 100
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
```

So ondemand mode works great, except it does not kill children after they've been idling for 10s. Also, setting pm.max_requests to any realistic value doesn't help.

My box is Debian 8.1, php5-fpm is running with nginx, nothing special in their configuration.

Answer (score 1):

in the main config file `/etc/php5/php-fpm.conf` set the value for:

`pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s`

in the individual pool config only set:

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 100
```

`php5-fpm -t` is helpful to test configuration.

Setting all 3 values in the pool config file gave me an error of:

```
value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY
```